# Should we minimize the sum of training error and cross validation error for training?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, validation, supervised-learning

Specifically, if we are fitting regression models using polynomial functions. For each model we can also calculate a cross validation error for the degree of that model. For example, if a model is a polynomial of degree 2, we also compute a cross validation error of degree 2. And the sum of this validation error and the training error of that model should be a better approximation of testing error. Shouldn't we use this sum as the object function for training?

Comment: To clarify: when you say that you're calculating a cross-validation error for the degree, do you mean that you are trying out many different degrees (1, 2, 3, etc.) and calculating the cross-validation error for each degree that you try?

Comment: sure, that is what I mean.